# Getting a Linking Error for C Program in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have been trying to find out why i'm getting this specific error when gcc tries to link the object files together:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
main                                /usr/local/gcc_4.7.1/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.7.1/crt1.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to complex
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Call the code you are viewing are given to use. The purpose was to be able to understand makefiles and link all of these files together on gcc. I believe the problem is coming form the makefile or the main.c. Please help i have been trying to correct this for hours. The commands i have been using are:

```
make makefile
gcc complex.c -o complex -lm
```

I have thoroughly searched the web to find what is causing this but none of them make any sense to me. Below i will put my three files that i am trying to link together: complex.c, main.c complex.h and my makefile.

complex.c:

```
 // Figure 11.10  Partial Implementation of Type and Operators for Complex Numbers
    /*
     *  Operators to process complex numbers
     */

    /*  User-defined complex number type */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "complex.h"


    /*
     *  Complex number input function returns standard scanning error code
     *    1 => valid scan, 0 => error, negative EOF value => end of file
     */
    int
    scan_complex(complex_t *c) /* output - address of complex variable to 
           fill     */
    {
          int status;

          status = scanf("%lf%lf", &c->real, &c->imag);
          if (status == 2)
                status = 1;
          else if (status != EOF)
                status = 0;

          return (status);
    }

    /*
     *  Complex output function displays value as (a + bi) or (a - bi),
     *  dropping a or b if they round to 0 unless both round to 0
     */
    void
    print_complex(complex_t c) /* input - complex number to display   */
    {
          double a, b;
          char   sign;

          a = c.real;
          b = c.imag;

          printf("(");

          if (fabs(a) < .005  &&  fabs(b) < .005) {
                printf("%.2f", 0.0);
          } else if (fabs(b) < .005) {
                printf("%.2f", a);
          } else if (fabs(a) < .005) {
                printf("%.2fi", b);
          } else {
                if (b < 0)
                      sign = '-';
                else
                      sign = '+';
                printf("%.2f %c %.2fi", a, sign, fabs(b));
          }

          printf(")");
    }

    /*
     *  Returns sum of complex values c1 and c2
     */
    complex_t
    add_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2) /* input - values to add    */
    {
          complex_t csum;

          csum.real = c1.real + c2.real;
          csum.imag = c1.imag + c2.imag;

          return (csum);
    }

    /*
     *  Returns difference c1 - c2
     */
    complex_t
    subtract_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2) /* input parameters    */
    {
          complex_t cdiff;
          cdiff.real = c1.real - c2.real;
          cdiff.imag = c1.imag - c2.imag;

          return (cdiff);
    }

    /*  ** Stub **
     *  Returns product of complex values c1 and c2
     */
    complex_t
    multiply_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2) /* input parameters    */
    {
          complex_t cmul;
          double a, b, c, d;
          a = c1.real;
          b = c1.imag;
          c = c2.real;
          d = c2.imag;

          if (( b > 0 && d < 0) || (b < 0 && d > 0))
          {
              cmul.real - (a*c) + (fabs(b)*fabs(d));
              cmul.imag = (a*d) + (b*c);
          }
          else if (( b>0 && d>0) || (b<0 && d<0))
          {
          cmul.real = (a*c) - (b*d);
          cmul.imag = (a*d) + (b*c);
      }
          return (cmul);
    }

    /*  ** Stub **
     *  Returns quotient of complex values (c1 / c2)
     */
    complex_t
    divide_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2) /* input parameters     */
    {
          complex_t cdiv;
          double a, b, c, d;
          a = c1.real;
          b = c1.imag;
          c = c2.real;
          d = c2.imag;

          if ( b > 0 && d < 0)
          {
              cdiv.real = (a*c) - (fabs(b)*fabs(d)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
              cdiv.imag = (a*d) + (b*c) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
          }
          else if ( b>0 && d>0)
          {
              cdiv.real = (a*c) - (fabs(b)*fabs(d)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
              cdiv.imag = ((-1*a*d) + (b*c)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
      }
          else if (b<0 && d<0)
      {
             cdiv.real = (a*c) + (fabs(b)*fabs(d)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
             cdiv.imag = ((-1*a*d) + (b*c)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
      }
      else if (b<0 && d<0)
      {
            cdiv.real = (a*c) + (fabs(b)*fabs(d)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
            cdiv.imag = ((a*fabs(d)) + (b*c)) / ((c*c) + (d*d));
      }
          return (cdiv);
    }
    /*
     *  Returns absolute value of complex number c
     */
    complex_t
    abs_complex(complex_t c) /* input parameter                        */
    {
          complex_t cabs;

          cabs.real = sqrt(c.real * c.real + c.imag * c.imag);
          cabs.imag = 0;

          return (cabs);
    }
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "complex.h"

int main (void)
{
      complex_t com1, com2;

      /*  Gets two complex numbers  */
      printf("Enter the real and imaginary parts of a complex number\n");
      printf("separated by a space> ");
      scan_complex(&com1);
      printf("Enter a second complex number> ");
      scan_complex(&com2);

      /*  Forms and displays the sum    */
      printf("\n");
      print_complex(com1);
      printf("  +  ");
      print_complex(com2);
      printf("  =  ");
      print_complex(add_complex(com1, com2));

      /*  Forms and displays the difference                 */
      printf("\n\n");
      print_complex(com1);
      printf("  -  ");
      print_complex(com2);
      printf("  =  ");
      print_complex(subtract_complex(com1, com2));

      /*  Forms and displays the multiplication */
      printf("\n");
      print_complex(com1);
      printf("  *  ");
      print_complex(com2);
      printf("  =  ");
      print_complex(multiply_complex(com1, com2));

      /*  Forms and displays the division   */
      printf("\n");
      print_complex(com1);
      printf("  /  ");
      print_complex(com2);
      printf("  =  ");
      print_complex(divide_complex(com1, com2));

      /*  Forms and displays the absolute value of the first number     */
      printf("\n\n|");
      print_complex(com1);
      printf("|  =  ");
      print_complex(abs_complex(com1));
      printf("\n");

      return (0);
}
```

complex.h:

```
typedef struct {
      double real, imag;
} complex_t;

int scan_complex(complex_t *c);
void print_complex(complex_t c);
complex_t add_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2);
complex_t subtract_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2);
complex_t multiply_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2);
complex_t divide_complex(complex_t c1, complex_t c2);
complex_t abs_complex(complex_t c);
```

makefile:

```
complex: main.o complex.o
    gcc -o complex main.o complex.o -lm
main.o: complex.h
    gcc -c main.c
complex.o: complex.h
    gcc -c complex.c
```

Comment: You might be just missing the `-f` option to specify the input file when calling `make` (ie. try `make -f makefile`, or simply `make` which uses the default `makefile` file)

Answer (score 2):

Just type `make`

More traditional is to spell the main make file "Makefile" (capitalized M).

If you want to name the makefile something else like Makefile.common, for example you need to be explicit with the -f option: e.g. `make -f Makefile.com`

I don't see anything wrong with the make file itself.

Comment: `make` looks for both `Makefile` and `makefile`.

Comment: From the GNU Make manual: By default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run the `gcc` command, you just need `make`. i.e.

```
$ make
$ ./complex
```

With your gcc command you're trying to compile `complex.c` separately into a binary executable file, which of course won't work because it doesn't have a main function.

If you want to compile the binary using `gcc` directly, just include both source files:

```
$ gcc -o complex main.c complex.c -lm
```